# Is it possible to choose a garbage collection algorithm in GWT or any other JavaScript framework

Tags: javascript, gwt, browser, garbage-collection

I want to know if its possible to choose a GC algorithm via code or by some other way 
(like specifying GC algo for JVM) in javascript or any JS frameworks.

Comment: It'd depend completely on the VM implementation, and I've never heard of any such thing. The closest I can imagine would be the indirect control you have in Rhino via the Java VM options, but there's no telling even then how that'd affect Rhino (JavaScript).

Comment: js garbage collection will depend on browser implementation, so it's least likely there is an universal solution. As far as I know the JavaScript language specs does not cover such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set the GC algorithm with GWT. GWT compiles to Javascript. So at runtime you only have Javascript on the client. Javascript apps inside the browser do not have the ability to set how the Javascript VM manages memory.